# Split bolt connection. Wire direction

Tags: splicing

Should the wires being hooked up in a split bolt connector be running side by side, like in a wire nut connection, or running towards each other, in opposite directions. Or does it matter?
[image]

Comment: A picture or two? Not sure what you mean by a split bolt ... a split pin however...

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkzfhkwsdXfP33nyLQR0M-bnMjb3k_9R0ZBTvqZ27tk0Hn7knXUA

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkzfhkwsdXfP33nyLQR0M-bnMjb3k_9R0ZBTvqZ27tk0Hn7knXUA

Comment: Sorry, trying to copy and paste a pic of the connector. Will try again

Comment: Edit the question and click the insert-picture button. You can't put a picture in a comment (and edits are better when you are adding more information, too).

Answer (score 3):

You can have wires entering from one side or both sides.

If I have 4 wires and I can arrange them neatly to come from both sides then I tend to do 2 and 2...

But if 4 on one side is neatest or convenient...